# How do I properly install these new RAM sticks?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I have purchased two new RAM sticks:

- [Crucial Pro RAM 32GB Kit (2x16GB) DDR4 3200MT/s (or 3000MT/s or 2666MT/s) Desktop Memory CP2K16G4DFRA32A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C29R9LNL)

I cannot figure how to properly install them in place of my old RAM such that my PC will achieve 3200MT/s and 32GB

Motherboard (MSI Z170A PC MATE) manual can be [found here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z170A-PC-MATE/support#manual).

I have tried slotting in the new RAM in place of my old RAM (2400, 8GBx2, 1.2V), but this leads to the PC not booting, with a red LED on the DRAM persisting.

The PC boots if at least one of the old RAM sticks is in place, even if the new RAM sticks are in place with it, resulting in 24GB or 40GB of RAM but with 2400 speed instead of 3200.

I have tried resetting CMOS via removing the motherboard battery, unplugging and switching off PSU, then touching the JBAT1 prongs together with a screwdriver, then holding the power button for 10 seconds, then removing and reinserting the new RAM sticks, but this does not result in successful boot.

Comment: that memory is not on the memory compatibility list - so, no guarantees it would work

Comment: The manual states: 4x DDR4 memory slots, support up to 64GB. Supports DDR4 3200(OC)/3000(OC)/2800(OC)/2600(OC)/2400/ 2133 MHz. So I think the RAM you bought is of a higher spec (DDR4 3200MT/s (or 3000MT/s or 2666MT/s)) than the system expects.

Comment: We need a part number for the original memory. What firmware revision are you running?

Comment: @Ramhound The old RAM sticks do not have a brand name on them, only "panram" 8 times and "DDR4-2400 8GBx2 1.2V" on a sticker. From msinfo32: BaseBoard is Z170A PC MATE (MS-7971) and BaseBoard Version is "2.0".

Comment: I don’t need a brand name. I need a part number.